# Show Object by Time-Dependent

Tags: java, android, object, timer, show

How can I do an event like the picture below? I tried with the countdown timer, but I couldn't succeed because one triggered the other before time ran out.

Thank you.

[image]

My code

```
    private void Test(final ArrayList<String> obj, final ArrayList<Integer> Times, final ArrayList<String> ObjectType) {
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++) {
        final Integer ShowTime = Times.get(i);
        final String OName = obj.get(i);
        final String OType = ObjectType.get(i);
        //Show time is numerical variable


        if (OType.equals("Image")) {
            final ImageView Resim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.container).findViewWithTag(OName);


            new CountDownTimer(ShowTime, ShowTime) {


                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                    Resim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }

                public void onFinish() {

                    Resim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }

            }.start();
        } else if (OType.equals("Buton")) {
......
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your countdown timer code

Comment: have you tried Handler ?

Comment: @NagvadiyaVishal No. how can i do it?